# Kubernetes: Display Pods by age in ascending order

Tags: sorting, kubernetes, kubectl

I use below command to sort the pods by age

```
kubectl get pods --sort-by={metadata.creationTimestamp}
```

It shows up pods in descending order. How can we select sorting order like ascending?

Comment: You can try something like this `kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | sort -r` little hacky way.

Comment: @mchawre my output looks like `18m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate ...`. It is likely that there are other units, too. If the output starts with `50s`, then `sort -r` will create undesired results.

Answer (score 21):

Not supported by `kubectl` or the `kube-apiserver` as of this writing (AFAIK), but a workaround would be:

```
$ kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | tail -n +2 | tac
```

or if tac is not available (MacOS X):

```
$ kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | tail -n +2 | tail -r
```

If you want the header:

```
$ echo 'NAME                                                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE' | \
 kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | tail -n +2 | tac
```

You might just have to adjust the tabs on the header accordingly. Or if you don't want to use `tail -n +2` you can use `--no-headers`. For example:

```
$ kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp --no-headers | tac
```

Comment: `--no-headers` like Amit's answer would save the need for `tail -n +2`, no?

Comment: if you want headers `kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | {head -1;tail -r}` also works

Answer (score 13):

**It Is Quite EASY**: Once you have used `--no-headers` option, the HEADER will not be part of output (ascending ordered-listing of pods) and you can simply *reverse sort* the outcome of the command.

Here's the complete command to get exactly what is expected:

**`kubectl get po --sort-by={metadata.creationTimestamp} --no-headers | tac`**

Comment: I like this answer best.

If you are also just looking for the newest, `k get po ... | tail -n 1` also works, without paying for tac.

Comment: To install `tac` on macOS run `brew install coreutils`

Answer (score 7):

Sorted `kubectl` output and `awk` provide the table view with a header. Installation of extra tools is not needed.

```
# kubectl get pods --sort-by=.status.startTime | awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "tac"}'
```

An approach with JSON processor offered by [paulogrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5363751/paulogrell) works also but could require more effort: for some Linux distributions you'll need to download and compile `jq` from source code. As for the `jq` command line I'd suggest to add  the "name" to the `map` parameters and sort by "timestamp":

```
# kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items | group_by(.metadata.creationTimestamp) | map({"name": .[0].metadata.name, "timestamp": .[0].metadata.creationTimestamp, "count": length}) | sort_by(.timestamp)'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to find the latest pod, try:

```bash
kubectl get pod --selector='app=my-app-name' \
  --sort-by='.metadata.creationTimestamp' \
  -o=jsonpath='{.items[-1].metadata.name}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Kubernetes API doesnt support this option yet, but as a workaround you can use a JSON processor (jq) to adjust its output.

**Ascending**

```
kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items | group_by(.metadata.creationTimestamp) | map({"timestamp": .[0].metadata.creationTimestamp, "count": length}) | sort_by(.count)'
```

**Descending**

```
kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items | group_by(.metadata.creationTimestamp) | map({"timestamp": .[0].metadata.creationTimestamp, "count": length}) | sort_by(.count) | reverse'
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version that works on MacOS and retains arbitrary headers:

```
kubectl get node --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | { read -r headers; echo "$headers"; tail -r; }
```