# view error pods below which is below 5 days

Tags: kubernetes, devops

I need to list the error pods below 5 days with all the columns. I have tried the below command, but no luck. I am getting some random pods and age. Could someone help to get only error pods which are below 5 days.

```
kubectl get pod --all-namespaces --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | awk 'match($5,/[1-5]+d/) {print $0}' | grep "Error"


NAME               READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod1                0/1     Error       0          63d
pod2                0/1     Error       0          24d
pod3                0/1     Error       0          11d
pod4                0/1     Error       0          4d16h
pod5                0/1     Error       0          15h
```

Comment: can you please check the output of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`. I see `6` headers for my cluster: `NAMESPACE  NAME  READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE`. could that be a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes: Display Pods by age in ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57294739/kubernetes-display-pods-by-age-in-ascending-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question I would like to point out **4 different things**.

**First**, the use of the regular expression in your example is not correct. The following regular expression:

```
[1-5]+d
```

will match not only `1d`,`2d`,`3d`,`4d` and `5d` as you intended but it will also match `63d` or `24d`. Why ? Firstly, because you used `+` [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) which *repeats the previous item once or more.* so it will match even `345d` if you have such `Pods` running in your k8s cluster. Secondly, you didn't specify that it should start from a number between 1 and 5, it only says that it should occur somewhere (e.g. in the end) in the matched string, so `[1-5]d` will also match `63d` because it will be able to find `3d` in it. The correct form of this regular expression looks like this:

```
^[1-5]d
```

Here we specify that it should match only strings which start with exactly one digit in range from 1 to 5 followed by `d` character.

So `awk` part of your command may look as follows:

```
awk 'match($5,/^[1-5]d/) {print $0}'
```

**Second**, note that when you run:

`kubectl get pod` with `--all-namespaces` flag, the output contains 6 columns, not 5, as already mentioned in comments by [Krishna Chaurasia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5147259/krishna-chaurasia). Additional column with `NAMESPACE` header is added. Compare 2 following results:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
my-release-mysql-0                  1/1     Running            0          12d
```

and

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default       my-release-mysql-0                                         1/1     Running            0          12d
```

`AGE` becomes 6th column so your command (or specifically its `awk` part) should rather perform the match on column `$6`:

```
awk 'match($6,/^[1-5]d/) {print $0}'
```

**Third**, as to the last part of your command i.e.:

```
grep "Error"
```

such filtering can be done by `kubectl` based on `--field-selector` e.g.:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Pending --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | awk 'match($5,/^[1-5]d/) {print $0}'
```

**Fourth**, it should be noted that in your example you're filtering out all the `Pods` which `AGE` is counted in other units like `hours`, `minutes` or `seconds`. If it's intended, just ignore the next paragraph.

However if you don't want to filter out all newer `Pods`, where `AGE` cannot be counted in `days`, you may modify your command so it shows `Pods` that were created `1-5 days` or `any number of seconds/minutes/hours` ago:

```
kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | awk 'match($5,/^[1-5]d|[1-9]+h|[1-9]+m|[1-9]+s/) {print $0}'
```